# Changing keyboard layout from terminal on opensuse

Tags: terminal, opensuse, keyboard-layout

I am trying to bind shortcuts for keyboard layouts.
For example:

- `Shift+Alt+1` - change to US layout
- `Shift+Alt+2` - change to UA layout
- `Shift+Alt+3` - change to RU layout

instead of change it with `Super+Space`.

In Ubuntu I used to bind such shortcut to `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1`, but in opensuse it doesn't work.

It is possible to do somehow?

Comment: You could maybe use `setxkbmap`. http://linux.die.net/man/1/setxkbmap

Comment: It is change layout only for terminal, isn't it?

Comment: No. The x in its name is for X11.

Comment: It didn't work for me, it changed it only in terminal, but not, for example, in browser. And indicator in tray didn't change.

Comment: :/ Maybe Gnome is messing with it; it works for me on Openbox. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with little trick.

I created script with such content (for each keyboard layout):

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'ru')]" &&
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru'), ('xkb', 'ua')]"`

And bind custom shortcut that run this script.

This script changes list of layouts, left there only one layout, because of it system change layout, and then I change list of layout to initial state.